# Win key (keyboard button) not working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently updated my Windows 7 x64. Before the updates, everything was working correctly, no issues.  After updating, my keyboard's Windows key is not working and neither are its shortcuts.  I checked it with [KeyTest](http://www.passmark.com/products/keytest.htm) - button is not working. I tried to locate **Scanncode** registry, but I found nothing. I also tried to remap the Windows key hoping that Scancode Map might reappear, but no luck.

I am using the Aero theme and my graphic card is HD radeon 7870.

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment: @99572 Yes i did